# Rxjava, combineLatest with RxTextView memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, rx-java, rx-kotlin, rx-binding

I'm trying to use combineLatest with several RxTextViews and I thought that I was disposing my Disposables properly but it looks like I'm still getting a memory leak.

```
val one = RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents(one)
            val two = RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents(two)
            val three = RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents(three)
            val four = RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents(four)
            val five = RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents(five)

            val disposable = Observables.combineLatest(one, two, three, four, five) { oneEvent, twoEvent, threeEvent, fourEvent, fiveEvent ->
                 //combining happening with these strings: oneEvent.view().text.toString  }
                    .skip(1) 
                    .debounce(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe {
                        //network call
                    }
            compositeDisposable.add(disposable)
        }
```

And then in my `onStop` I dispose of it.

```
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    if (!compositeDisposable.isDisposed) {
        compositeDisposable.dispose()
    }
}
```

I read that if some Views are referenced in the onNext() method, then there’s a potential NullPointerException which is what I believe is happening. Here's my NPE I'm getting:

```
fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: view == null
       at com.jakewharton.rxbinding2.internal.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:27)
       at com.jakewharton.rxbinding2.widget.RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents(RxTextView.java:159)
       at MyFragment$setUpTextListeners$1.execute(MyFragment.kt:170)
```

Here's the fragment I'm using:

```
private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel
private lateinit var binding: FragmentMyThingsBinding

private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    binding = FragmentMyThingsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
    binding.viewModel = viewModel

    //calls to kick off business logic

    return binding.root
}


override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    setUpTextListeners()
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    if (!compositeDisposable.isDisposed) {
        compositeDisposable.dispose()
    }
}

private fun setUpTextListeners() {

    val one = RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents(one)
    val two = RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents(two)
    val three = RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents(three)
    val four = RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents(four)
    val five = RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents(five)

    compositeDisposable.add(Observables.combineLatest(one, two, three, four, five) { oneEvent, twoEvent, threeEvent, fourEvent, fiveEvent ->
            //combine here using oneEvent.view().text.toString  }
            .skip(1)
            .debounce(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {
                //network call
            })

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your views, that you pass to `RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents`, is null. There is [assert in that function](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/master/rxbinding/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/rxbinding2/widget/RxTextView.java#L159), that checks incoming argument on `null`.

And that problem is not connected with memory leaks.

EDIT:
Changing the synthetic view property to use `binding.editText` fixed the issue. (Discussion in comments)

Comment: That's correct. But it's only happening every now and again and I can't pinpoint exactly why. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide code of `MyFragment` class? Need investigate it to help you.

Comment: Added the fragment

Comment: I should also mention that I'm using a view pager that spins up `newInstance`'s of this fragment for each page.

Comment: Is that code correct `val one = RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents(one)`? Where passed to function `one` argument is defined?

Comment: Yes, `one` is the id of my textview.
`import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.my_fragment.*`

Comment: Could you try to replace `one` -> `binding.one`, `two` -> `binding.two` and etc. Will that problem be reproduced or not?

Comment: Wanted to wait a minute before accepting this just to make sure that fixed it, but it looks like it did! Fingers crossed!